# Go stack trace for docker daemon hang

Tags: docker, go

Docker daemon hangs initialization, and the Go stack trace for the daemon appears to be hanging in a particular stack. I'm not a Golang person, so requesting help interpreting this call stack:

```
goroutine 1 [syscall, 15 minutes, locked to thread]:
syscall.Syscall6(0xc000d11ce0?, 0xc000e2b1e0?, 0xc000dbe97e?, 0xc000dbeaa0?, 0x55c538c76a4e?, 0xc000b39f70?, 0x1?)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go:91 +0x36
os.(*Process).blockUntilWaitable(0xc0004ffe60)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/os/wait_waitid.go:32 +0x87
os.(*Process).wait(0xc0004ffe60)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x28
os.(*Process).Wait(...)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/os/exec.go:132
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc000d11ce0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/os/exec/exec.go:890 +0x45
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0x2?)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/os/exec/exec.go:590 +0x39
os/exec.(*Cmd).Output(0xc000d11ce0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/os/exec/exec.go:984 +0xc7
github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).fillPlatformInfo(0xc0009f26c0, 0xc000581000, 0xc000e45200)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/info_unix.go:48 +0x38a
github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).SystemInfo(0xc0009f26c0)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/info.go:68 +0x818
github.com/docker/docker/daemon.NewDaemon({0x55c53aed0258?, 0xc00015ad70}, 0xc000204f00, 0xc000a4f830, 0xc0000524e0)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:1140 +0x3006
main.(*DaemonCli).start(0xc00061f240, 0xc000999490)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go:232 +0xae9
main.runDaemon(...)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/docker_unix.go:14
main.newDaemonCommand.func1(0xc000004c00?, {0xc0002300f0?, 0x1?, 0x1?})
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/docker.go:39 +0x94
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc000004c00, {0xc00012c010, 0x1, 0x1})
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916 +0x862
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc000004c00)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1044 +0x3bd
github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968
main.main()
        /build/docker.io-app-24.0.5/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/docker.go:109 +0x18c
```

Following the source code, appears that this is the last line in moby code before hang:
https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v24.0.5/daemon/info_unix.go#L48
Is that the correct interpretation? Or am heading in the wrong direction?

Full details are here: https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/201
I'm trying to refine the github question by doing as much troubleshooting as I can.

I'm expecting the docker daemon to start without issue. But in certain environment (namely AWS w/ EBS encryption enabled), the docker daemon hangs.

Comment: It is running the executable "configStore.runtime", which is not returning

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar for the response. Since original post, I have been able to verify it was actually `runc --version` which is what I originally guessed. Turns out if I run that command in cli directly, it hangs exactly how dockerd hangs. Ultimately, when I swap runc with crun, it works! Must be a bug with runc.